# ClassCastException on dataset.show

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My schema:

```
 StructField[] fields = new StructField[] {
     DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.LongType, true),
     DataTypes.createStructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true)
}

StructType schema = new StructType(fields);
```

I'm reading multiple CSV files due to non supported compressing I'm not using `.read().csv()`. Anyhow I read my CSV file after uncompressing it. I go over each line and create a new Row from line split by the delimiter: ,

```
List<Row> rows = new ArrayList();
Row row = RowFactory.create(line.split(","));
rows.add(row);

List<Tuple2<String, List<Row>> csvRows = new ArrayList();
rows.add(new Tuple2("..", rows);
```

My lines in CSV are as such:

```
"1","ABCD"
"2","EFGH"
```

When I try to create a `Dataset<Row>` from my list and call show on it I get a `ClassCastException String cannot be cast to Long`.

```
Dataset<Row> set = spartSession.createDataFrame(csvRows.get(0)._2, schema);  
set.show();
```

But "1" should be castable from String to Long.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast from String to Long, just try this:

```java
Long number = (Long) "1";
```

This will not compile with the message `Cannot cast from String to Long`, which is completely normal. Long is not a subclass of String.

If I unserstand your code correctly, you first have to parse the value (which is a string) from the row before passing it to `createDataFrame`.

Something like that:

```java
Long.parseLong(csvRows.get(0)._2)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

[JavaDoc for ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)

It states that:-

> Thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. For example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:
>
> ```
> Object x = new Integer(0);
> System.out.println((String)x);
> ```

**Solution:-**

Use `Long.parseLong(String)` method to convert String to Long